# QWebSocketServer won't accept SSL connections from Windows Firefox

Tags: windows, qt, firefox, ssl, websocket

I have a Qt application that runs a QWebSocketServer in secure mode (SSL) with certificates from Letsencrypt. Everything works fine when I connect from Chrome or Edge on my Windows 10 machine.

I'm using this facility for testing: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

But it doesn't work when I connect from Firefox in Windows 10. However, it does work when connecting from Firefox running on Linux in VMware on the same machine. When it doesn't work, I mean that none of the callbacks of QWebSocketServer gets called: neither newConnection, nor acceptError, peerVerifyError, sslErrors, or serverError (I implemented all these callbacks to try to debug it). Also, on the websocket side, I get some error message after a few seconds:

```
ERROR: undefined
DISCONNECTED
```

I also tried to connect from my Windows 10 machine from a different network location. And it worked! But only for a while. After several trials, it failed repeatedly and systematically.

Also, I tried from a different Windows 10 machine and it worked. But again, only for a few trials and afterwards it failed repeatedly and systematically.

I tried the following with no success:

- clear the Firefox cache.
- uninstall and re-install Firefox (I'm using version 52).
- run Firefox Developer Edition.
- run Firefox from a different user account.
- restart the server machine (Ubuntu 16.04).
- restart the client machines (Windows 10).

When I remove the Secure mode in my QWebSocketServer everything works with non-secure WebSockets.

On the server machine, tcptrack displays the Firefox connection, as "ESTABLISHED", but QWebSocketServer apparently receives nothing (no callback method gets called).

It seems QWebSocketServer is receiving the connection request, but failing to answer and to call any error callback method (via Qt signals).

I am running out of ideas to understand what's the problem.

What could I try next?

Comment: To further investigate, I compiled the http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-sslechoserver-example.html and replaced the cert and private key files by mines. Same results: works from Chrome/Edge, not Firefox/Windows 10. So the culprit is not my application.

Comment: I also ran a SSL websocket server with python and tornado on my server machine (with the same cert and private key). And it works from Firefox/Windows 10, but not the Qt WebSocket SSL echo server example. So, it seems the culprit is Qt...

Comment: I am using the Qt 5.8.0 on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 (64 bit) and just found a bug report that might explain the problem: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57665

Comment: Found the solution: by applying the patch proposed in bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57665, the bug is gone.

Comment: I was about to tell you to make sure this wasn't simply a firewall issue... Anyways, you should probably answer your own question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: the issue was indeed a bug in Qt 5.8.0 as reported here: bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57665. The fix proposed in the discussion of this bug report actually fixed the problem.